# Getting specific data by column using sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I couldn't give a good title to the problem I'm having, but basically I have two columns `Name` and `MaxNum` string and int respectively!
I need `int` method that makes a query which retrieves the `MaxNum` for specific `Name` that I give in parameter!

.. so if I have this data

**ID** | **Name** | **MaxNum**

0 | Mike | 50

1 | John | 40

2 | Jess | 30

..when I put `Jess` in as parameter it will return 30 !

My method so far.. but I can't use it since it doesn't return `int` value !

```
public void  maxFromName(String name){

  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_MAX + " FROM "+ TABLE_AZKAR+" WHERE " +COLUMN_NAME+ "=" + name ;
  db.execSQL(query); 
}
```

Comment: Just parse it using Integer.valueOf(yourvalue);

Comment: @Amy parse what exactly ? the method ?!

Comment: No.. the return value

Comment: well, I can't just return `db.execSQL(query);` it's void !? can u give me an answer so that I can try it..!?

Comment: Instead of using raw SQLite, I'd suggest you go for ORM like [GreenDao](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/). 

A little difficult to begin with, but it'll make your life much much simpler once you get used to it. Also, it makes db handling easy when your application starts to get more complex.

See [link](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/) for details.

Comment: @SamZar Just change your function code with the my answered function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rawQuery` for getting data from SQLite. And from the cursor get integer value using getInt function.

Change your `maxFromName` function with the following.

```
public int maxFromName(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_MAX + " FROM "+ TABLE_AZKAR+" WHERE " +COLUMN_NAME+ "= '" + name +"'" ;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(c.getCount()!=0){
            c.moveToFirst();
            return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("MaxNum"))
          }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what the selectQuery?

Comment: @AliAhsan sorry for mistake in the race forgotten to change the variable name

Comment: hehehe it happens :)

Comment: same error as @Neeraj method > `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Jess (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _max as maxValue FROM azkar WHERE name_col=Jess`

Comment: I have update the query copy and paste it into your project

Comment: this now > `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`

Comment: it worked now.. the last error was in result of me adding a wrong column name inside `...getColumnIndex("MaxNum")`  used the constant instead of `"MaxNum"` ! it works great now..! thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

You have to get the result using 
[Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html)

```
String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_MAX + " FROM "+ TABLE_AZKAR+" WHERE " +COLUMN_NAME+ "=" + name ;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
c.moveToFirst();   
return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("MaxNum"));
```

**Update**

Since you are facing the problem, I suggest you use the below query:

```
String query = Select MaxNum from azkar WHERE Name ='Jess';
```

after this use my code from `Cursor c` line, this will work.

Comment: gives me this error > `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Table`

Comment: @SamZar Try now!

Comment: why not [c.getInt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt(int))

Comment: @ScaryWombat fixed

Comment: @NeerajJain what if it doesn't return anything?

Comment: gives me this now > `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Jess (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _max as maxValue FROM azkar WHERE name_col=Jess`

Comment: @SamZar your Select query is wrong, it should be `Select MaxNum from azkar WHERE name_col='Jess'`

Comment: Your constant COLUMN_NAME seems to be wrong. It must match the column name in the DB. Also it might be that you have to encapsulate your name in inverted comma ('').

Comment: @M.Schwarzer-Haverbier I'm using the same constant for creating the table and its columns ! what do you mean by `encapsulate your name in inverted comma ('')` !?

Comment: Look at Amys query. There are inverted commas around name.

Comment: @NeerajJain The column iin the question s called 'Name' not ''name_col'.

Comment: @M.Schwarzer-Haverbier there is a lot of confusion just because of invalid constant used, Gave him the actual fix now all he has to do is figure out what went wrong. So much comments just create confusion

Comment: @NeerajJain haha agree with you

Comment: You right guys, the error was in result of me adding a wrong column name inside ...getColumnIndex("MaxNum") I used the constant instead of "MaxNum".. it works now..! please excuse my silliness '_'

Answer (score 2):

In the API it says the following in the description of `execSQL()`:

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL
>   statement that returns data.

Use a query method that returns a `Cursor` type in order to retrieve results

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get a single value from a database is with the [stringForQuery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#stringForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) or [longForQuery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) helper functions:

```
public long maxFromName(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT "+COLUMN_MAX+" FROM "+TABLE_AZKAR+" WHERE "+COLUMN_NAME+" = ?";
    return DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, query, new String[]{ name });
}
```

(To prevent string formatting problems and SQL injection attacks, always use [parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) instead of inserting string values directly into the query.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use rawQuery

```
public ArrayList<String> maxFromName(String name){

ArrayList<String> maxNums = new ArrayList<>();

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_MAX + " FROM "+ TABLE_AZKAR+" WHERE " 
+COLUMN_NAME+ "=" + name ;

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
c.moveToFirst();  
do { // if that kind of rows are more then one, this metod get all of them
maxNums.add(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("MaxNum")));
}
return maxNums;
}
```